# Cannot return to the start slide after slickNext() and slickPrev()

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I used slick to get carousel functionality:

```
    $('.modal-slider .slick').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        fade: true,              
        asNavFor: '.modal-slider-nav .slick'
    });

    $('.modal-slider-nav .slick').slick({
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        asNavFor: '.modal-slider .slick',
        dots: false,
        centerMode: true,
        focusOnSelect: true,
        variableWidth: true,            
        prevArrow : '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left prev"></i>',
        nextArrow : '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right next"></i>'
    });
```

In the modal window I do:

```
    var imagesModal = $('#imagesModal').modal({
        show: false
    }).on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {     
        $('.modal-slider .slick').slick('slickNext');  
        $('.modal-slider .slick').slick('slickPrev');                      
        $('.modal-slider .slick').delay(1000).show();
        $('.modal-slider-nav .slick').delay(1000).show();
    });
```

But slider moves to the second image and does not return to the first image.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Click the `<>` and create a [mcve] - we cannot guess how your HTML looks like. Include the relevant HTTPS JS files and show a working carousel